# Detect shaking when using the draggable interaction

Tags: javascript, events, jquery-ui

Something like this perhaps?

```
$('#drag').draggable({
    shake: function(){
        alert('Shake event invoked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to implement that using some mouse gesture recognizing software.

One implementation is the [$1 Unistroke Recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/).

[Moousture](http://ajaxian.com/archives/moousture) may also work for this.

Of course, you could also roll your own by calculating direction changes and using a timout to determine when enough of them have occurred within a suitably short period of time to constitute a shake.

Good luck!